# Algebra homomorphisms are identified with evaluation at semisimple elements

Tags: representation-theory, algebraic-groups

For $G$ a semisimple simply connected linear algebraic group, $R(G)$ its representation ring, there is a canonical embedding of algebras $$ R(G) \hookrightarrow \mathcal O(G)^G = \{\text{regular class functions on } G\} $$ obtained by mapping a representation to its character.
Here, I understand a regular class function to mean a class function $ G \to \mathbb C$ that is regular in the sense of a morphism of varieties.
It is a 'well-known fact' that if $G$ is reductive then the induced map given by complexification of the left-hand side $$ \mathbb C \otimes_{\mathbb Z} R(G) \to \mathcal O(G)^G$$ is an isomorphism.

Now any algebra homomorphism $R(G) \to \mathbb C$ can be identified with evaluation of a character $z \in R(G)$ at a *semisimple element* $a \in G$, where here I take semisimple to mean a diagonalisable element, i.e. up to conjugation lies in (some) maximal torus $T \subset G$. **Why is this bijection true?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because for $f$ a class function on $G$ and for $x \in G$, $f(x)=f(x_s)$, where $x=x_sx_u$ is the semisimple-unipotent (Jordan-Chevalley multiplicative) decomposition. Thus really we identify maps $R(G) \to \mathbb C$ with evaluation at any element of $G$, but we may as well take its semisimple part (since there is a nice bijection of semisimple classes with elements of $T//W$).